# Downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 to file copied to DVD disc, won't open on Win XP pro, asks for program to open it?

Tags: 12.04

Tried IE to open 12.04 but it will not.  What to do? How do I open it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Before posting a question you should search the site for similar issues, an answer might already exist.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open an Ubuntu iso file on Windows XP.Using that file just create a bootable Ubuntu usb through unetbootin software or burn the iso file as image to a dvd for creating bootable Ubuntu dvd.

After creating bootable Ubuntu disk,boot from it to install Ubuntu alongside with XP.

If you want to view the contents of that iso file,then install *Magic iso* software on your Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the disc from your explorer (My Computer>D:, where D: is your DVD Drive)? Can your machine reads the contents of your DVD? I remember the iso image provided is in CD format (not DVD format), so it is best to use a blank CD and burn the iso image again.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, you need to use a burning program to burn the image. The burning program automatically decompress the iso image and burn all those files to the disc. You can't just choose to write data CD and put the iso image file to burn.